# John the Ripper password cracker is viable?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

Is this still viable? I remember using this when it just worked in shells.

http://www.openwall.com/john/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  I believe JTR, [Hashcat](https://www.hashcat.net), and [InsidePro](http://www.insidepro.com/) are the three dominant password crackers these days.  You may find it lacking features that the others have or vice versa.

All three have teams using them pretty successfully in the major password cracking competitions, like [Crack Me If You Can](http://contest.korelogic.com/).